# Naming a method which modifies data in place in Python

Tags: python

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from utils import gen_x

@dataclass
class Data:
    x: str
    
    def foo():
        self.x = gen_x()

d = Data('bar')
d.foo()
```

I need to modify `x` in place from usability reasons, but I don't know how to clearly indicate that in name of method which performs that modification (named here: `foo`).

Rejected names:

- generate_x - means, that x is generated and returned, not substituted in instance
- substitute_x - better than previous, but looks strange

Comment: Property getters and setters typically use the convention of `get_<prop name>()` and `set_<prop name>()`. That said, voting to close this as being potentially opinion-based. If you want more info on properties in Python, [see here](https://realpython.com/python-getter-setter/)

Comment: set_x looks good, cause its kind of dynamic setter. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`update_x` or `replace_x` - These two names would be better if you want to  modify the x attribute in place

Comment: Please do not answer opinion-based questions. Flag for closure as such.